# How to use querySelectorAll() to get an element by the value of its property?

Tags: javascript, dom

Given some elements like `<section style="order: 1">`, `<section style="order: 2">`, and `<section style="order: 3">` how can I use `querySelectorAll()` to get the first, ie, that in which the value of `order` is `1`?

Not sure how to get past this: `document.querySelectorAll("[style]")`

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('[style="order: 1"]')`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#attrvalue) as `[attr='value']`.

```js
document.querySelector("[style='order: 1']");
```

Comment: How about for the element `<li id="li0" tabindex="1" style="order: 1; background: yellow none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">First</li>` ?  Using `document.querySelector("[style='order: 1']")` yields `null`. How can I select based only on `order: 1` ?

Comment: @zadrozny `document.querySelector("[style*='order: 1']");`